# Evaluating the generalized continued fraction obtained from the factorization of a bivariate polynomial equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, factorization, continued-fractions, irrational-numbers

Happy New Year, MO community!

We need someone expert in Generalized Continued Fractions (GCFs), with a deep knowledge of the GCFs’ convergence properties, to solve the following problem.

---

**PROBLEM**

Given a prime $p>2$, let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that $x>y>1$ and
$$ x^p-y^p=1 \tag{1}$$
Let us factorize Eq. **(1)** by $x-y$ as
$$ (x-y)^p+pxy(x-y)R=1 \tag{2} $$
where $R$ is a bivariate polynomial $R(x,y) \geq 1$; it is routine to verify that $R=1$ if $p=3$ whereas $R>1$ for any prime exponent $p>3$.
Let us rearrange Eq. **(2)** conveniently as
$$ (x-y)((x-y)^{p-2}(x-y)+pxyR)=1 \tag{3} $$
Let us put $a=pxyR$ and $b=(x-y)^{p-2}$ in Eq. **(3)**:
$$ (x-y)((b(x-y)+a))=1 \tag{4} $$
with $a>p$ and $b<1$ because, respectively, $xy>1$ and $x-y<1$.
From the factorization of Eq. **(4)** we obtain a recurrence relation:
$$ x-y = \frac{1}{a+b(x-y)} \tag{5} $$
with $a>pb$.
The recursive Eq. **(5)** generates a generalized continued fraction (GCF):
$$ x-y = \cfrac{1}{a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{a + \ddots \vphantom {cfrac{1}{1}}}}}} \tag{6} $$
Can you prove (or disprove) that the GCF **(6)** converges to an irrational limit?

---

**OBSERVATIONS**

The irrationality of $x-y$ via the possible convergence of GCF **(6)** meets only half of the two-fold Lagrange’s criterion recalled in https://mathoverflow.net/q/383280.

PROS: the partial denominator $a$ is at least $p$ times the partial numerator $b$ (they are both real numbers).

CONS: the partial numerator $b$ is smaller than one and the partial denominator $a$ is extremely likely not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $x-y$ does not have to be irrational.

Indeed, take any rational $r>0$ small enough so that
$$(1+r)^p<2.$$
Let
$$f(y):=(y+r)^p-y^p.$$
Then $f(1+)<1$ and $f(\infty-)=\infty$. Also, $f$ is continuous on $(1,\infty)$. So, $f(y_*)=1$ for some $y_*\in (1,\infty)$. That is,
$$x_*^p-y_*^p=1,$$
where $x_*:=y_*+r>y_*>1$, but $x_*-y_*=r$ is rational.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Iosif! It confirms that the two-fold Lagrange criterion for the General Continued Fractions to converge into an irrational number is a condition both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @Monk : Thank you for your appreciation. [These guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) may now be relevant.